# Scope with functions in C

Tags: c, function, scope

I'm trying to make the main function short. I need to answer some questions ( many lines of code each, inside every questions, I need to use variables declared in main)
But using functions, the way I Know how to use then, won't be useful, 'cause I need to use inside every question lots of variables, different types, and not arrays. 
Sorry for my english, It's hard to explain what I need.

this is my code mixed with pseudocode (simplified)

```
int
main(void)
{
    int x = 4;
    int y = 5;
    float z = 6.8; // And lot of more variables like this

    answer_1;  //pseudocode
    answer_2:  

    return 0;
}
```

//   inside answer1 there are lots of printf's showing the value of variable x, y, z.... etc)

//   inside answer1 there are lots of printf's showing the value of variable t, i, l.... etc)

Comment: "I need inside a function to use a variable declared in Main." - wait, isn't that exactly what function arguments are for?

Comment: bring that or those variables outside the body of main as `static int x = 4;`.  At least that way their visibility is limited to the current compilation unit (file) as opposed to a global var that becomes visible all over the project.  However, even with static vars a slightly more telling varname than `x` would probably be a good idea.

Comment: Consider using structs and/or arrays to reduce the number of arguments to be passed.

Comment: @pmod that's a main that's so short that it doesn't even return the promised return value I guess..

Comment: Ok, Let me try to explain it better. I meant that I need a line of code (like a function call) that executes many lines of code outside main, to make main's code short. A used x as an example here, I konw that's bad coding.

Comment: @jotape Just use fubctions and pass arguments. If you have variables which are like global options (such as parsed command line args), then making those global variables is quite ok practice.

Answer (score 1):

With the code sample you've posted, the best way to pass in x is as an argument to the function.

```
void func(int x);

int main(void)
{
    int x = 4;
    func(x);
    return 0;
}

void func(int x)
{
    printf("X = %d", x);
}
```

If this won't work in your real code, could you post a longer example?

Comment: Ok, but what if a have 20 variables to pass, different types, not arrays. What I'm trying to do is calling a function (in my example) for every answer in a list of requirements. Is just to make more readable my code to my teacher.

Comment: If you've got a lot of state that you want to pass around to different functions, I'd recommend grouping the values logically into [structs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)), or pointers to structs. Are there logical groups between the variables? eg, fooA, fooB, fooC, could all be stored in one struct foo, with members a, b, c.

Comment: Also, if you have 20 parameters, then you perhaps need to break things up into multiple functions.  The struct approach to encapsulating a comprehensive state is also advisable, as noted above.

Comment: @Douglas may be a Struct is what I'm looking for. I'll dive in Structs.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pass these variables to the function, you can either

- Declare the variables as global, and you can access them in every functions.
- Use GCC's nested function feature (see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) . But this feature is for GCC only, so you should not use it in a portable program.

Comment: To the OP: don't do this.  Nobody writes C this way, for good reason.  Use parameter passing the way it's intended.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out, that global variables (both static and exported) are generally a bad practice, and something totally horrendous if they are used to replace function parameters. It's like using a singleton in an OOP language to pass method parameters...

Comment: @Joe I'm learning; perhaps using a function in my example is not what I need. I'll change the question so it can be understand the way I intended

Comment: One notable exception: it is quite normal to make truly shared stuff into global (or static) variables, like options parsed from command line arguments. Basically anything which would make sense to be singleton in OOP language is good candidate for global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "function within another function"

function main will contain other two functions.
define variables first and then write function body.